# Magento Shipping-Estimator Block not updating

Tags: magento

When I try to increase quantity in the shopping-cart page, the shipping-estimator block does not get updated with latest shipping rates after the cart quantity has been updated. Any suggestion why it's not updating?

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your own functionality to modify quotes, you need to do this to recalculate totals:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```